# C++ primer 5th ed templates dependent and non-dependent names

Tags: c++, templates, dependent-name

In C++ Primer 5th edition Chapter16 on templates:

"It is up to the provider of a template to ensure that all names that do not depend on a template parameter are visible when the template is used. Moreover, the template provider must ensure that the definition of the template, including the definitions of the members of a class template, are visible when the template is instantiated."

But I think it is a mistake here: AFAIK non-dependent names on template parameter must be visible when the template is defined and not when "used".

Am I correct?

Here is my example:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T& )
{
    bar(); // non-dependent name
    void do_it(T); // dependent name
}

int main(){}
```

So the code should fail to compile although I didn't instantiate `foo` but doesn't complain about declaration of `do_it` as long as being a dependent name.

So is this a typo n the book?

Comment: `void do_it(T);` is a function *declaration*. It *declares* that such a function with that signature exists "somewhere". It doesn't need a prior declaration because *it is* a declaration.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: I am talking about `bar` not `do_it`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: I mean non-dependent names must exist priorly like  `bar` even if the template is not used "thus instantiated". is it correct?

Comment: You are ignoring the possibility of a misbehaving compiler. How many different copilers did you try?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: inf fact Just GCC